# How to run buildozer under virtualenv?

Tags: android, python-3.x, pip, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to build an APK from a Kivy project written in Python 3.5 using Buildozer. Everything is installed within a virtualenv. When I run:

```
buildozer -v android debug
```

I get the following error:

```
Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
# Command failed: pip install -q --user "appdirs" "colorama>=0.3.3" "sh>=1.10" "jinja2" "six"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I understand that the flag `--user` doesn't make a sense within a virtualenv. Probably, by default Buildozer works not under a virtualenv. Is there a way to say to Buildozer to skip this flag? Or maybe there're different solutions?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [a known problem](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/509) with buildozer. My solution would be to rename `pip` to `pip.real` in the virtual env and replace `pip` with a shell script that removes `--user` from arguments and pass args to `pip.real`. Something like [this](https://github.com/sjml/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh.d.symlink/functions/pip) but not exactly. May be like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
args=''
for arg in "$@"; do
    [ "$arg" == "--user" ] || args="$args $arg"
done
exec pip.real "$args
```